# How to create SharePoint Subsite Template for Sharepoint 365?

Tags: sharepoint-online, template

I recently started working with SharePoint Online and am looking to have a set of Document Libraries to be included with new Subsites. Will I be able to accomplish this with SharePoint Designer 2013? Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

For reference, I have already tried recovering the Site Actions for generating templates, but to no avail.

*Update- I was able to use SharePoint Designer and a new temporary subsite to create the template! Thanks for the help!

Comment: you want create a new subsite but it include couple of libraries, right? is it only time or multiple time? you want to use same template?

Comment: Correct, I would like to have a couple of libraries copied when a new subsite is created. It would be used multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a template you should first create a subsite with the required design, then save it as a template using the OOTB tools in the UI by navigating to `Site Settings>Site Actions>Save as Template`

Note, however, that if publishing features have been enabled on your site collection you will not be able to save the site as a template. A SharePoint tenant administrator would have to create a new site collection without publishing features enabled, and you could recreate the site there and save the site template, however it will only be available within that site collection. To use it in your primary site collection you will have to export the solution as a package and import it with the solutions gallery.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/save-download-and-upload-a-sharepoint-site-as-a-template

Answer (score 0):

Frist of all , you need to create a new subsite for design .

Then if you want the subsite include couple of libraries which they are already existing in root site , you can save the lists/libraries as template and then add the template to your subsite .

1. save your library/list as a template , you can do this in Site Action --list/library -- on the ribbon ,click on list settings -- save list/library as template . fill the file name and template name etc.
2. go to your subsite and click on Site Action -- Site Content --add an app , search the name of the template and add this app .

Now you can see the list/library is on your subsite . If you have multiple lists or libraries , you can repeat above steps .